# Identity user in new entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to make an ASP.NET MVC Project.
I have a forum controller with a `SubmitPost` action. Here is the code for the action:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Submit(PostSubmitViewModel model)
{
    if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var category = this.categoryService.GetById(model.CategoryId);
    var user = this.userManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

    this.postService.Submit(new Post
    {
        Title = model.Title,
        Content = model.Content,
        Category = category,
        Author = user,
    });
    return RedirectToAction("Category", "Forum", new { id =  model.CategoryId });
}
```

As you can see there is a `postService` and `userManager`. They are injected by Ninject and they both use the same DbContext - per request scope. Login, Register all work as expected.

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();

    // Identity bindings
    kernel.Bind<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().To<UserStore<ApplicationUser>>().InRequestScope()
        .WithConstructorArgument<DbContext>(kernel.Get<ApplicationDbContext>());
    kernel.Bind<IAuthenticationManager>().ToMethod(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
}
```

The post service does only this:

```
public void Submit(Post post)
{
    this.context.Posts.Add(post);
    this.context.SaveChanges();
}
```

My problem is that when the action is called i get an exception:

`An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.`

at this line:

```
this.context.Posts.Add(post);
```

I'm pretty sure i have only one dbContext instance for both the service and userManager. When I insert the post with a `null` author it works fine. I guess EF is trying to save the existing user again but I don't get the same error with the category that also comes from an external service and already exists. I tried putting a breakpoint on `MyDbContext`'s constructor and it's only called once. Maybe there is something specific about UserManager that I don't know about?

Here is my user manager class:

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
        // Validation configs etc.
```

I have no idea what exactly is causing the exception so any ideas would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With limited access to the code I can only suggest:

on the object `Post` create a property `AuthorId`

Then change

```
var user = this.userManager.FindById(this.User.Identity.GetUserId());

this.postService.Submit(new Post
{
    Title = model.Title,
    Content = model.Content,
    Category = category,
    Author = user,
});
```

to

```
var userId = this.User.Identity.GetUserId();

this.postService.Submit(new Post
{
    Title = model.Title,
    Content = model.Content,
    Category = category,
    AuthorId = userId,
});
```

If the above doesn't work, on the class `Post` decorate the property `Author` with `ForeignKey(nameof(AuthorId))`

this is all i can give at the moment without more information. I hope it helps

Comment: Thank you, it worked! However, Is it normal that i cannot use the instance of the user directly through userManager even though everything uses the same dbContext?

Comment: It depends on the situation. Let me explain to you what's happening and that might help you. Full context is always better.

1. when you create a new instance of an object and attach it to the context. the change tracker is tracking the object (or entity) as an 'Add' state. Including all it's properties (the user).
2. when SaveChanges() is called. All the nav properties of 'Post' are also being 'Added'. EF then gets confused because a user with that ID already exists, but you are trying to add it to the DB.


if the above solution worked. Can you kindly mark it as the 'answer'?

Comment: I think I understand, but why doesn't it happen with the category which also exists?

Comment: I cannot be sure unless I debug the application myself. As a rule of thumb here. I always prefer to use Id properties rather than navigation properties for this type of reason. EF state is hard to debug (or atleast I find it hard)

Comment: Actually that's what I did yesterday. I added an id property on every navigation property and I also skiped some unnecessary database queries this way. Thanks for the help.